# I cant open localhost with chrome [error 400]

Tags: localhost

**Problem** : Localhost not working with chrome, but works fine with firefox.

**Program** : AppServ 9.

**Error** :

[image: Bad Request]

**What i tried**:

1. Re-install appserv.
2. Try "xampp".
3. Clear browser cashe.

**Edit** : Localhost is working with chrome in **Incognito** mode.